# UIAlertController not showing when moved to another swift file

Tags: ios, swift, methods, viewcontroller, uialertcontroller

So I have built my single view application in swift and Xcode. All my code is in one file, the main `ViewController.swift` to make things easier as the codes get bigger I have started to move the methods to a separate swift file to keep things organise - `ClipManager.swift`.

I have 3 methods which all use the `notifyUser` method which calls `UIAlertController`.

So I have moved this method to the same file, `ClipManager.swift` but now my Alerts are not showing when these methods are called in the current ViewController - `ViewController.swift`as the methods are in a separate file.

Firstly my Method that uses UIAlert

```
////Located in ClipManager.swift
class ClipManager: UIViewController {
func notifyUser(title: String, message: String) -> Void
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
            style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }}
```

The call of my Method from `ViewController.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
///// In ViewController.swift (where I want the Alert to show)
let SavedRecord = MyClipManager.SaveMethod(publicDatabase!, myRecord: record)
```

}

The code for `SaveMethod` located in `ClipManager.swift`

```
 func SaveMethod(publicDatabase: CKDatabase, myRecord:CKRecord ) -> CKRecord {

        publicDatabase.saveRecord(myRecord, completionHandler:
            ({returnRecord, error in
                if let err = error {

                    //// **** Notify called here *****
                    self.notifyUser("Save Error", message:
                        err.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.notifyUser("Success",
                            message: "Record saved successfully")
                    }


                }
            }))
     return myRecord
    }
```

I'm guessing my Alerts are not showing because they are actually being triggered on `ClipManager.swift` which isn't in view.

What are my options here, Move `NotifyUser` back to `ViewController.swift` and create and object of this in `ClipManager.swift` to call it in my methods located there?

Or is there a way to pass these Alerts to the shown view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi here how i will do in your place.

For my ClipManager class it will extends from NSObject. no need from UIView controller

here how the class should look like

```
class ClipManager: NSObject {
func notifyUser(title: String, message: String) -> Void
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
        style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
}
```

for presenting the alertView i use the `rootViewController` of the application

No change to make in your ViewController class.

let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much! this has worked perfectly...

Could you explain to me how this has changed, I understand that rootviewcontroller is picking the first view controller?

Why is it changed to NSObject?

Comment: for the NSObject it just to tell you that you could use a simple swift class for the notify management.
the rootView controller is the Root View Contains Your Content

Comment: The `NSObject` part is irrelevant to the solution, everything in Swift inherits from `NSObject` and there's no difference between explicitly inheriting it here in your class file and not including it.

Comment: yes i know. i did this just to show that have modified the ClipManager super class. thanks @pbush25 for your precession :)

Answer (score 2):

I used BEN MESSAOUD Mahmoud way of doing things, but ran in to a small error at time with:
"Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

I wound up changing it a bit to solve this. I pass the view controller along with the call to notifyUser. Then it will present from whatever VC I am in.

```
func notifyUser(title: String, message: String, fromController: UIViewController) -> Void{
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
    message: message,
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
    style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelAction)
fromController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
    completion: nil)
}
```

then I would just call it:

```
Clipmanager.notifyUser("title", message: "message", fromController: self)
```

Got some help with this from Sulthan  on this link [AlertController is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

**Update of Stan and BEN MESSAOUD's answers for Swift 3:**

```
class ClipManager: NSObject {

func notifyUser(title: String, message: String, fromController: UIViewController) -> Void
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                  message: message,
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                     style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    fromController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

And to call it:

```
let clipMGR = ClipManager()

clipMGR.notifyUser(title: "Title", message: "Message", fromController: self)
```