# Unable to present UIAlertController within a UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have got a **UIAlertController** that I would like to present within a **UITableViewController**. However when I run the code I get the following error:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

My code seem to reflect what suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy). What am I doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Check for force touch feature, and add force touch/previewing capability.
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
    }
    else {
        // Create an alert to display to the user.
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: "3D Touch Not Available", message: "Unsupported device.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alertController!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, in **viewDidLoad** you still don't have a view in the window hierarchy, like said in message. Try to move your code to **viewDidAppear** instead