# Attempt to present alertcontroller whose view is not in window hierarchy

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uialertcontroller

I'm getting the following error in Swift 3:

```
Attempt to present alertcontroller whose view is not in window hierarchy
```

I have already referred to other posts on this topic to no avail. More specifically, I've implemented the change suggested in this post: [AlertController is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

and I'm still receiving the same error.

What I've done is:

1. Create an AlertHelper.swift helper class:

   ```
   class AlertHelper {
   ```

   func showAlert(fromController controller: UIViewController) {
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Try Again", message: "Email Already In Use", preferredStyle: .alert)
       controller.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   }
2. In my View Controller, under a function which is called when a button is pressed, I check to see if an email address entered by a user is already stored in my Firebase database, and if so, I try to present an "Email already in use" alert from the AlertHelper class:

   ```
   Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error)     in
           if error != nil {
               if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                   switch errCode {
                   case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                       let alert = AlertHelper()
                       alert.showAlert(fromController: self)
                       return
                   default:
                       print("other error")
                   }
               }
           }
           else {
               // Inputs user email into database
               self.ref.child("Users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["Email": email, "Location": ""])
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "todorm", sender: self)
           }
       }
   ```

The database stuff works, the only thing that isn't appearing is the alert. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of a strange practice to subclass your alert into a separate class.

You should try making a method in your ViewController class

```
func showAlert() { 
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Try Again", message: "Email Already In Use", preferredStyle: .alert) 
   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Call the method using:

```
self.showAlert()
```

Comment: I've tried that method too, and I still get the same UIAlertController not in window hierarchy error. Here's the strange thing: when I try to present an alert in a simple if-else statement, it works. However, when I try to present the alert in an if statement nested within another function call (as shown above), I get the error.

Comment: Check if the createUser method creates a controller instance. It is possible that it presents a new controller on top of the existing controller so when you try to present on your existing controller, the error occurs.

Comment: I suspect that this is the case. If so, how would I go about fixing it?