# Swift: UIAlertController inside while loop

Tags: ios, swift

Struggling with the following code:

```
 var connected = false
    while !connected {
        let msg = "Press cancel"
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            connected = true
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        print ("Hello")
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

1. The UIAlertController is never shown, "Hello" is printed over and over again
2. If I insert "connected = true" after the while clause then the UIAlertController is shown, but I'm not able to show it again by changing the action to "connected = false"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you keep showing the alert controller in a endless loop? Think it it's not reasonable. Keep the logic just show the alert controller in specific condition.

Comment: Once you break out of the while loop it will not be executed any more. And what William is saying is true, please don't do this.

Comment: Well, it was just an example, what I would like to do was the user to leave the app and connect to an external wireless network and have a "Try again" button to check it the connection was ok. Hence, instead of "connection = true" I would have a something like " if networkOk {connected = true} If not ok, show the alert controller again...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, its not a good idea to present your alert controller continuously in a while loop. I believe your intended functionality is to display an alert whenever the `connected` variable becomes false.

To accomplish this use `NotificationCenter` to respond as follows:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.displayAlert), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "connectionDropped"), object: nil)
```

Add a `willSet` property observer to `connected`:

```
var connected: Bool! {
  willSet {
    if newValue == false && oldValue != false {
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "connectionDropped"), object: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Then whenever you set `self.connected = false`, you will run this method:

```
@objc func displayAlert() {
  let msg = "Press cancel"
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
  let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
    self.connected = true
  }
  alert.addAction(action)
  print ("Hello")
  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Just make sure you set connected after the view hierarchy has been loaded e.g in `viewDidAppear`.

Once you're done with the view you can then remove the observer:

```
deinit {
  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "connectionDropped"), object: nil)
}
```

EDIT:

The functionality you need is provided with the [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) framework, in particular with the `reachabilityChanged` notification. You can then call the `displayAlert` using a similar approach that I outlined above; this is documented on their README document.

Comment: Also, make sure you remove the observer when you're done with the view.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The UIAlertController is never shown, "Hello" is printed over and over again

It is *inappropriate* to keep presenting the alert in an endless `while` loop, probably, it leads to facing "[AlertController is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)" issue.

> 2. If I insert "connected = true" after the while clause then the UIAlertController is shown, but I'm not able to show it again by
>      changing the action to "connected = false"

Of course you won't be able to show it again by default, the chunk of code is already been executed.

**Solution:**

Presenting the alert should be related to triggering a *specific* condition, not in a `while` loop.

For instance, if you are aiming to notify the user that the device is unconnected, You could use [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) and observe `reachabilityChanged` to present the alert, for more details you could check the library - **Example - notifications** section.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using a recursive call to the function:

```
    func showDlg(){
    ssid = getWiFiSsid() ?? "AAA"
    ssid = ssid[ssid.startIndex..<ssid.index(ssid.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)]
    if ssid != "GP" {
        print ("SSID: " + ssid)

        let msg = "\nNot connected to GoPro camera\n\nPlease connect to camera wireless network and revert\n "
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "GoPro Golfswing Analyser", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Try again", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            print("Testing network again")
            self.showDlg()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)

        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            print("Cancel - exiting")

        }
        alert.addAction(action1)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else{
        print("Connected to GoPro")
    }

}
```