# Unable to use a custom view controller in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uiwindow

I am trying to use this controller to see what it looks like and decide whether or not to use it as a base in my own custom UIImagePickerController: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/PhotoPicker_APLViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-PhotoPicker_APLViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_5

Right now I am calling the Delegate class without any problems. However, I can't seem to use the Controller like that suggested in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9YWkvjB_Qc (around 4:10). I tried writing `window? = APLViewController()`. But I get a black screen. If I set a size and color for the window in the delegate class it will get that.

Furthermore, the controller class in the video example or the controller I am trying to use does not have any `init` functions. So why would I assume something would be happening when creating an instance of it and setting it as my `rootViewController`? This controller has also no apparent void function to call but wants `UIBarButtonItems` as parameters.

How can I run this "APLViewController"?

Answer (score 0):

When working with `ViewControllers` it appears that there is no single `init` method. I worked my way through this "APLViewController", with simple `print` to console messages to understand better in which order it all ran.

As the instance variables where never initialized anywhere I tried doing it in the `viewDidLoad` function, leading me to ...`is not in window hierarchy` - error. In the answers here [AlertController is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) it was suggested doing it in `viewDidAppear` instead.

It did not exist so I override the `viewDidAppear` and initialized all the instance variables from there. Then fomr inside this function I could call all the functions within the class - and it all worked.