# Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: > > whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift4

I am trying to create and display an UIalert for my app. The alert is inside of the view controller and it will be called inside the api service call as follows.

```
    APIService().loginr(success: { result in
        print(result!)
        let json = result as! NSDictionary
        self.showResponseAlert(title: "Success!", message: json["message"] as? String)

    }, failure: {error in
        print(error!)
    }, parameters: parameters)
```

and my uiAlert

```
func showResponseAlert(title:String?,message:String?){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and also i tried

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async{
       self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

but didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AlertController is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257670/alertcontroller-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Comment: @Daniel no. ill update the question with my UIAlert

Comment: Did you assign rootViewController to any viewConrtoller in your project?

Comment: @DinithePieris the solution you marked as the answer is one of the answers shown in the question I referenced previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to present Alert.

```
func showResponseAlert(title:String?,message:String?){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            topController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```